# closure of a set $S$ and the set of the limit points of $S$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be a subset of topological space $X$. Let $S'$ be be the set of all limit points of $S$. Then, it can be shown that
$$\bar S= S \,\cup\, S',$$
where $\bar S$ denotes the closure of $S$, the smallest closed set in $X$ containing $S$.
Now, this is what I am accustomed to see as either the definition of $\bar S$ or as a proven theorem (e.g. in Munkres).

However, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265059/the-closure-of-s-is-the-set-of-all-limits-of-sequences-of-points-in-s-that-c) the relationship between $\bar S$ and $S'$ is portrayed as if $\bar S = S'$ instead of $S' \subseteq \bar S.$

I can think of counterexamples to $\bar S = S'. $ For example, $S = \{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, where $S' = \{0 \}.$

Am I simply misreading that post or missing something more fundamental? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems (to me) to boil down to whether one defines $S'$ as the set of all limits of sequences in $S$ (as i had been accustomed to doing) or, alternatively, as the set of all limits of *nontrivial* sequences in $S$ (as appears to be the custom on this site, and in various sources).

That is, if one includes "trivial" sequences,  $x_n=x$ for $x\in S$, then one gets $S\subset S'$, and so $\bar S=S'$.

Answer (score 2):

That question isn't asking about the limit points of $S$. It's asking about all possible limits (in *metric* space $X$) of sequences of points in $S$.

Comment: Isn't the set of limits of all convergent sequences in $S$ the same as the set of limit points of $S$? In other words, if $\{s_n\} \subset S$ and $s_n\rightarrow s$, can't we say that for all such $s$, $\{s\} = S'$?

Comment: @Neutrino No. For $s$ to be a limit point, we require that the sequence converging to $s$ doesn't have $s$ as a term. The question you linked has no such requirement.

Comment: No, $0$ is still a limit point of $[0,1)$.  For instance,  $\dfrac1n\to0$.

Comment: @Neutrino What Chris said above. There are sequences in $[0,1)$ which converge to $0$ but don't have $0$ as a term. Thus $0$ is a limit point.